# Display custom post types in grid Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I am trying to display custom post type (CPT) in a grid view similar to on this site:

[www.virtualpudding.com](http://virtualpudding.com)

I have thoroughly searched google and Stackoverflow to no avail. It needs to have a thumbnail just like the site linked above which when clicked follows through to a specific page. Basically it is a portfolio to show case work.

Currently i have a custom post type entitled 'Portfolio' and have created a very basic template to display these using the following code;

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Recipes Page
*
* Selectable from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
*/
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">
                           <?php query_posts( 'post_type=portfolio'); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I am not a php coder and have little knowledge of php coding and any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that your custom post type supports 'thumbnails'.

The wordpress function "register_post_type" takes an array where you can configure the custom post type. One of the array element is "supports" which allows you to specify what features the custom post type has.'

[register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

or [add_post_type_support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support)

Then, in the while loop, you can get the thumbnail by using [has_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail) and [the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)